# decide io_service number in app

Tags: c++, boost-asio

asio doc has 2 examples: "io_service-per-CPU" and "single io_service and a thread pool calling `io_service::run()`. What the difference in performance on a multi-CPU machine?

What's the principle that determine how many `io_service` I should use in my app? Should I share periodic timer's `io_service` with sockets' io_service?

Comment: similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010530/do-we-need-multiple-io-service-per-thread-for-threaded-boostasio-server-with also http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/asio-Performance-of-1-io-service-per-core-vs-1-io-service-run-by-thread-pool-td2641419.html hope this helps