# Do we need  multiple io_service per thread for threaded boost::asio server with a single acceptor

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

I am not much experienced in `boost::asio`. I've some pretty basic questions.

Do I need to have a different `io_service`, and a different `socket` under a different `thread` but one single `acceptor`, to process a client in a threaded server ?

I believe I must have a different socket for a new client. But if all threads use the same `io_service` would it be parallel ?

I was going through http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/index.html in asio section
which says I need to have different io_services in different threads to achieve parallelization.

I if I plan to make a Server class that creates a `new TCPsession` each time a new client appears in `acceptor.async_accept`
and `TCPSession` ctor creates an `io_service` and a `thread` and runs that `io_service.run()` in its own thread would it be a good design ?

However in this design where would I join all these threads ? do I need another `io_service` for `main` so that it doesn't terminate even before getting a new Client ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Single `io_service` running in a single thread can servce all the asio objects in your project. In such a design the i/o still would be "parallel" in the sense that it's non-blocking, asynchronous; but since `io_service::run()` is being run in one single thread, all the completion handlers would be invoked serially, one-by-one.

To scale your networking module over multiple CPUs, you can use one of the two approaches: thread-per-core, io_service-per-core - see [HTTPServer2 and HTTPServer3 examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).

In any case, creating a thread or `io_service` per `TCPSession` seems to me an unnecessary overhead - think of a case where you've got thousands of `TCPSession`s...

Comment: Then what will the per session threads do ? e.g. shouldn't I have one session in one thread ? to make each session parallel ? However I am supposed to have < 5 concurrent Sessions at once. Though I'd like to know the general purpose solution

Comment: No, you don't need that. Please read the following: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html .  The only case where you might need additional threads is if TCPSession completion handlers are too heavy (eg. perform time-consuming DB operations or so). But then your application wouldn't be scalable anyway, so you'd have to change the design to split or move some work out of completion handlers.

Comment: So If I just have a different socket per session It will be okay ? and can I develop the whole thing in single thread first ? and then switch to multiple threads ?

Comment: Of course, TCPSession would encapsulate its own tcp::socket, but all this sockets may be served by the same io_service (i.e. you can create them all with the same io_service). If you use io_sevice-per-cpu model, then you can develop TCPSessions with no regards to how many io_service's you will have eventually. Just create io-service pool (each io_service would be in its own thread), and every time you create TCPSession, take an io_service from the pool. Initially you can set the pool size to 1, and later increase it to {boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()} .